Forward traffic from Wi-Fi hotspot to SD-WAN (Zerotier)
I am not very experienced in linux networking so I'm not really sure if this is even possible, that's why I need your help.
Hardware setup:

Mikrotik hEX S - configured as a simple DHCP server - 10.0.0.0/16 - DHCP range: 10.0.0.100-10.0.0.200

Raspberry Pi#1 - raspiOS (Debian Bullseye) - 10.0.0.197 - joined to SD-WAN Zerotier network and configured as a layer 2 bridge following the next guide https://docs.zerotier.com/bridging/

Raspberry Pi#2 - raspiOS (Debian Bullseye) - SD-WAN address - 10.0.0.200 configured as a Wi-Fi hotspot using hostapd and dnsmasq, joined to the same SD-WAN Zerotier network


I have successfully configured the layer 2 bridge, in other words I can connect the Pi#2 to any LAN and communicated with devices behind Pi#1. But of course, I cannot do this if I connect to the hotspot of Pi#2. Is there any way to basically bridge/forward traffic from the Wi-Fi hotspot interface so it goes through the SD-WAN?
Basically my end goal is - connect Pi#2 to any LAN, connect a device to its hotspot and I want all of the traffic to go through the tunnel and using and ip address which is behind Pi#1 and not Pi#2's public IP in the current LAN, where it may be.
If anyone could give any kind of tips I would be grateful.

To bridge the traffic from the Wi-Fi hotspot interface on Raspberry Pi #2 (Rpi2) through the SD-WAN using ZeroTier, you'll need to configure Rpi2 to forward traffic from its hotspot interface to the ZeroTier interface, which is part of the Layer 2 bridge.
Before you change this, make sure you backup your configuration files!
I'd believe you've already made sure that the Rpi2 is configured to join the same ZeroTier network as Rpi1 and is properly authorized with the correct settings in ZeroTier Central.
# Install ZeroTier
curl -s https://install.zerotier.com | sudo bash

# Join ZeroTier Network
NETWORK_ID=<your-network-id>
sudo zerotier-cli join $NETWORK_ID

Then configure Wi-Fi hotspot on Rpi2, I'm assuming you have already configured the Wi-Fi hotspot using hostapd and dnsmasq.
The enable IP forwarding to allow traffic to be forwarded from the Wi-Fi interface to the ZeroTier interface:
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
sudo sed -i 's/#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1/net.ipv4.ip_forward=1/' /etc/sysctl.conf

Then configure iptables to forward traffic from the Wi-Fi interface to the ZeroTier interface. Example:
# Replace wlan0 with your actual Wi-Fi interface name
WIFI_IFACE=wlan0
ZT_IFACE=zt3jvirser  # Replace with your actual ZeroTier interface name

# Flush existing rules
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -t nat -F

# Set up NAT for traffic from the Wi-Fi interface
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $ZT_IFACE -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i $ZT_IFACE -o $WIFI_IFACE -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i $WIFI_IFACE -o $ZT_IFACE -j ACCEPT

# Save the rules
sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4"

Then, you need to make sure that the Wi-Fi interface is part of the bridge, which allows devices connected to the hotspot to communicate over ZeroTier.
Modify /etc/systemd/network/25-bridge-br0-wlan.network to add the Wi-Fi interface to the bridge:
[Match]
Name=wlan0  # Ensure this matches your Wi-Fi interface name

[Network]
Bridge=br0

Finally, restart the services:
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl restart hostapd
sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq


Thanks a lot for the help, I've done this but unfortunately this process breaks my previously configured Wi-Fi hotspot, it is still up but the clients get an APIPA IP address, something messes with the DHCP server...
I realise for me to do

sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4"

I have to install iptables-persistent, because the file doesn't exist originally. After that all the iptables get migrated to the rules.v4 file.
Still I feel this is really close, I'll try to investigate further. If you have any ideas, I'd be very grateful.
